# Dynamic File Outbound Gateway based on header

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'd like to archive files that come in on a directory based on \name\date structure - so even every day the directory will change. Any suggestions appreciate.

I'm was on track to create a file outbound-gateway where the directory is dynamic, where the header is enriched with a method that generates the path of the directory.

I was thinking of something like this

```
<file:outbound-gateway id="archive" request-channel="input"
reply-channel="channel" directory="@Header[archiveLocation]}"
mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true">
</file:outbound-gateway>
```

But it doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

Based on previous related answers, I'm familiar with the samples at
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/dynamic-ftp-outbound-adapter-context.xml

My concern of doing it this way is, would there be any resource issues if I need to create tens, or hundreds of different outbound-gateway?

Since I can put the data in the header, is there an easier way to do it. Or is the directory field set at context initialization, and cannot be dynamic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After finally creating an account on Stack Overflow all these years to post a question, found the answer later. I can use directory-expression.

```
<file:outbound-gateway id="archive" request-channel="input"
reply-channel="channel" directory-expression="headers.archiveLocation"
mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true">
</file:outbound-gateway>
```